# How to do a sumif formula based on criteria in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a sumif formula that is based on a letter in column N. Right now my formula gives me a value error and I am trying to fix it. My current formula looks like this:
    =IF($N$4:$N$51="S",SUMIF($E$4:$E$51,H91,$L$4:$L$51),"")
I am trying to say, if the letter in column n is S, then sumif this formula. My sumif formula is correct, just getting it to only add up the rows that have an s in column n is where it is wrong.

Comment: would there have to be two sumifs in this formula?

Comment: Change to SUMIFS() with a S

Comment: =SUMIFS($L$3:$L$55,$N$3:$N$51,$G$91,$E$3:$E$51,H91) this is still giving me a value error

Comment: Your ranges are different sizes.

Comment: `=SUMIFS($L$3:$L$55,$N$3:$N$55,$G$91,$E$3:$E$55,H91)` ranges must be the same size.

Comment: The SUMIF compares the values in E4:E51 where H91 value is found.  Does H91 has a value that matches any of those in E4:E51?